# how to fix the dashboard diagnostic errors?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I run the dashboard and I get the following errors:

/ kobuki: Stale
/ input ports: Stale
/ sensors: Stale

I can not put the full mode turtlebot due to these errors. Any suggestions?
(the communication between the workstation and the PC turtlebot working properly)

thank you very much for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66788/how-to-fix-the-dashboard-diagnostic-errors?/) by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stale usually means no data. So, you probably didn't start the driver or something else failed. Look at the startup outputs of the turtlebot.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0